# JQuery how to select parent but not children

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Sorry for what is probably an easy question, but I haven't found a way to make this work yet.  I'm new to JQuery and I've got some nested lists which I'm trying to add a click event to a parent list which will slideToggle the children lists, which I've got working, however if I click on any of the children lists, it will also trigger the slideToggle.  Is there a way to specify a selector to perform an action when just a parent class is selected but NOT any of the children?

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".liClass1").on("click", function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(this).find(".ulClass2").slideToggle();
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
  <form>
    <ul class="ulClass1">
      <li class="liClass1">
        <span>liClass1</span>
        <ul class="ulClass2">
          <li class="liClass2">
            <span>liClass2</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you with a Snippet if you have a couple of minutes.

Comment: You can use `parent()` of the clicked element and prevent to continuation of the script according to the parent's properties.

Comment: @SimonArnold I've added the code snippet for this example

Comment: @Mike It appears the problem was your selector was targeting multiple elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".liClass1").on("click", function(event){
        $(this).children("ul").slideToggle();
   });

   $(".liClass2").on("click", function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
   });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
  <form>
    <ul class="ulClass1">
      <li class="liClass1">
        <span>liClass1</span>
        <ul class="ulClass2">
          <li class="liClass2">
            <span>liClass2</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  This works great for my example above.  For some reason it's not working in my real project, but I should be able to apply this to figure it out.

Comment: Glad it helped you. If you're still blocked on your real project, don't hesitate  to ask. We will help!

Comment: Turns out I was dealing with two issues.  The first, which you kindly helped with.  And second was that I was working with dynamically added elements.  Found some answers about event delegation and I'm good to go.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You added a click handler on `liClass1`. When you click on a `ulClass2` element, it will trigger the same handler, because it is nested within `liClass1` so the event will be propagated up!

The Solution is to discard any click events on `ulClass2`:

`$('.ulClass2').on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
})`

Comment: I added a code snippet to demonstrate this example.  I also removed the 'not' portion of the selector, and it is behaving the same way (clicking on the span under liClass2 still activates the slide toggle, and so that span is hidden).

Comment: This is a great explanation, thank you!  Now I just need to make it work with my real project :)